# How is the string terminator '\0' has the same value as integer constant 0?

Tags: c, arrays, string, null, language-lawyer

I have the following code -

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define LENGTH 5
int main(){
    char* ch[LENGTH] = {"Zero", "One", "Two", "Three", "Four"};
    char* pc;
    char** ppc;
    for(int i=0; i<LENGTH; i++){
        ppc = ch+i;
        pc = *ppc;
        while(*pc != 0){
            printf("%c ", *pc);
            pc = pc +1;
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It is an example of multiple indirection using string.

The output is

```
Z e r o 
O n e 
T w o 
T h r e e 
F o u r
```

Here in `while()` loop instead of `*pc != '\0'`, `*pc != 0` is used.

But both the approaches give same output. Why is it so?

Comment: Answers will explain why. I'd just like to agree that it makes no sense to compare a character to an integer while processing characters. It should be either `while (*pc != '\0')` or _`while (*pc)`_.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Line feed `\n`, tab `\t` etc has their own escape sequence characters, but actually there does not exist one for the null terminator.

The industry de facto standard way of represending the null terminator is therefore to write an *octal escape sequence with the value zero*. Octal escape sequences are defined as `\` followed by a number. So `\0` simply means zero, with octal representation. Since this looks similar to other character escape sequences, it has become the de facto standard way of representing the null terminator.

This is why a decimal `0` works just as fine, it is just another way of writing the value zero. You could as well write `\x0` if you wish to be obscure.

Answer (score 8):

A `char` is really nothing more than a small integer, and as such are implicitly convertible to `int`. Furthermore character literals (like e.g. `'A'`) are really represented by the compiler as `int` values (for example  the literal character `'A'` is represented by the `int` value `65` in [ASCII](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/ascii) encoding).

The C language allows one to insert any arbitrary integer (that can fit in a `char`) using *escapes*. There are two ways to escape such arbitrary values, using [*octal*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal) numbers, or using [*hexadecimal*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal). For example, the ASCII value for A is `65`, that can be represented as either `'A'`, `'\101'` in octal, `'\x41'` in hexadecimal, ***or*** plain `65`.

Armed with that information it should be easy to see that the character literal `'\0'` is the octal representation of the integer `0`. That is, `'\0' == 0`.

You can easily verify this by printing it:

```
printf("'\\0' = %d\n", '\0');
```

---

I mentioned that the compiler treats all character literals as `int` values, but also mentioned that the arbitrary numbers using escaped octal or hexadecimal numbers needs to fit in a `char`. That might seem like a contradiction, but it isn't really. A characters value must fit in a `char`, but the compiler will then internally convert it to an `int` when it parses the code.

Comment: Note that in C they *are* `int`s. No conversion, however implicit, is therefore necessary.

Comment: Could not follow. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: @Suraj Every character can be represented by an ASCII value ranging from 0 to 255. The value of the ASCII of `NULL` is 0 so its return true when you compare it  with it. The same goes for the letter 'a' which has an ASCII value of 97 for example, if you compare `'a'==97` it will return `true`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I am sorry because my comment was obscure. I did follow your answer. What I could not follow is your first comment.

Comment: @Suraj Updated the answer to hopefully make it easier to understand.

Answer (score 4):

Adding to the existing answers, to look into the *sentinel*, quoting `C11`, chapter §5.2.1

> In a character constant or string literal, members of the execution character set shall be
>   represented by corresponding members of the source character set or by escape
>   sequences consisting of the backslash `\` followed by one or more characters. **A byte with
>   all bits set to 0, called the null character, shall exist in the basic execution character set; it
>   is used to terminate a character string.**

and from chapter §6.4.4.4/P12,

> EXAMPLE 1 The construction `'\0'` is commonly used to represent the null character.

So, a constant `\0` is the one which satisfies the aforesaid property. This is a *octal escape sequence*.

Now, regarding the value, quoting  §6.4.4.4/P5, (*emphasis mine*)

> The octal digits that follow the backslash in an octal escape sequence are taken to be part
>   of the construction of a single character for an integer character constant or of a single
>   wide character for a wide character constant. **The numerical value of the octal integer so
>   formed specifies the value of the desired character or wide character.**

so, for a octal escape sequence `'\0'`, the value is `0` (well, both in octal, as mentioned in §6.4.4.1, and decimal).

Comment: Backslash followed by `0` is an octal escape sequence. `0` in octal is `0`  (which actually is also octal for the same reason)

Answer (score 4):

`0` and `'\0'` are exactly the same value, and in C, are **both** `int` types. This is fixed by the C standard and is *irrespective* of the character encoding on your platform. In other words, they are *completely* indistinguishable. (In C++, the type of `'\0'` is a `char`.)

So `while(*pc != 0)`, `while(*pc != '\0')`, and `while(*pc)` for that matter are all the same thing.

(Personally I find the last one I give the clearest, but some folk like to use the `'\0'` notation when working with C-style strings.)

Comment: No it's well-defined C++ too, although in that language you'd be advised to use the `std::string` class from the C++ Standard Library.  Plus C++ compilers might complain more about the fact that the string literals decay to a `const char*` pointer, not a `char*` pointer.

Comment: What is the disadvantage of "using namespace std;" ?

Comment: @Suraj: That's a curve-ball for this question. Essentially it pollutes your global namespace.

Comment: what is the meaning of "pollute global namespace"?

Comment: @Suraj: Everything from `std` is available without the scope resolution operator. In large code bases that can cause clashes with other tokens and even wreak havoc with overload resolution. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice